# django ajax javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-2.7

**1**. I'm trying to add ajax to my django web application... The code i've written is given below... for testing i wanted to display a text in the html element whose id="id_ajax1"... the code successfully displays the text, **but it automatically reloads the page again**...

**2**. when I write the 1st one from the code given below this line, the behaviour is as mentioned above... when I write the 2nd one from the code below, it shows **broken pipe ('127.0.0.1', 46958)**

```
return HttpResponse("text to be returned asynchronously")

return HttpResponse("text to be returned asynchronously", mimetype="application/javascript")
```

---

**The code:**

**ajax.html**

```
<form action onsubmit="ajax1()">
 <span id="id_ajax1"></span>
 <button class="col-5" type="submit">click</button> 
</form>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function ajax1() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("id_ajax1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    var url = "test/ajax1";
    xhttp.open("GET", "/test/ajax1", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/ajax1/$', views.ajax1, name='ajax1'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def ajax1(request):
    return HttpResponse("You have successfully written your first ajax code")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues that could be causing this behavior:

1. You are submitting your form, therefore reloading the page. The `ajax1()` function should return `false` to prevent the browser from automaticly sending the form.
2. The url that is used in `xhr.open()` is not the same as the url defined in `urls.py`
3. I'm not sure what causes the broken pipe error. It might be the mimetype. `application/javascript` is used for sending actual Javascript code to the browser. The mimetype that you need for sending text (like with AJAX) is `text/plain`. In your case there is no need for defining the mimetype at all.